# Comparing NSString to an int getting NSInternalInconsistencyException

Tags: ios, swift

I am creating a Log in for my iOS App, and get an error `NSInternalIncosistencyException`.

Originally
`if (responseString=="1") {`
which never comes true for some reason so I change to the code below which returns true but causes an error?
`if (responseString?.intValue==1) {`

What's the way round this?

**Edit**
I am completely baffled by this problem. I have changed my PHP file to echo 'good' instead of '1' to try and cancel out the issue of comparing a String to Int.

This is my current code

```
let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: 
        String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
        let goodVal: NSString = "good"
        print ("responseString =\(responseString!))")
        print (goodVal)
        print(responseString==goodVal)
        if responseString == goodVal{
            print("IN LOGIN")
```

So this is what my code looks like which produces the output below 
[Display Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B8IDc.png)
So why on earth in the if statement doesn't become true?!

Comment: You should not use `NSString` in Swift at all.

Comment: Can you show the value of `dump(responseString)`

Comment: Why not? @vadian

Comment: Because Swift has its own (value) type `String`

Comment: @Paul.s what do you mean by dump? sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/OptionalChaining.html) sample under *Optional Chaining as an Alternative to Forced Unwrapping* section:

A part from link:

```
if let roomCount = john.residence?.numberOfRooms {
    print("John's residence has \(roomCount) room(s).")
} else {
    print("Unable to retrieve the number of rooms.")
}
// Prints "Unable to retrieve the number of rooms."
```

Use `IF..Let` to determine 'responseString' variable is populated or not and use it accordingly.

**EDIT:**

Based on your comment you can try like:

```
var responseString: String? = "1"

// example 1
if let responseCode = responseString {
    print("responseCode \(responseCode)")
    if(Int(responseCode) == 1) {
        print("responseCode is 1")
    }
} else {
    print("No response code")
}

// example 2
if responseString != nil {
    print("responseCode \(responseString!)")
}
else {
    print("No response code")
}
```

Comment: So this checks whether responseString has a value? If so, it will do section one of code otherwise will do section two?

Comment: If part prints output of roomCount that means if part runs when roomCount has value. Else part runs otherwise and displays a message of unavailability of value. You should first check if responseString has value and then compare it with your desired value.

Comment: I have tried this, and it errors 'NSInternalInconsistencyException'

Comment: This method works thank you! I found the error that I was getting was because I was trying to run UI on a thread other than the main one. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know if two string are equals you can use your first code:

`if (responseString=="1") { ... }`

If this never comes true its because the `responseString` is not "1" or it might be an optional that you must unwrap.

Comment: How can I 'unwrap'?

Comment: With ? Or ! After de variable. But I highly recommend you to read Apple`s swift documentation: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/optional

Comment: So I have unwrapped it, even printing out the variable to see what it is but still doesn't apparently equal what ever I put in the quote marks?

Comment: Did you print the variable `responseString`? Which is the output?

Comment: yes, print ("responseString =\(responseString!))") is what I print out and then in the If statement I put If(responseString=="WHATEVER GETS PRINTED OUT") and still doesn't return true